# How to solve $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\log(n-1)-\log(n)}{\log(n-1)\log(n)}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to solve the following series: $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\log(n-1)-\log(n)}{\log(n-1)\log(n)}$$

Here's what I did:
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\log(n-1)-\log(n)}{\log(n-1)\log(n)}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\log\bigl(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigr)}{\log(n-1)\log(n)}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{\log\bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigr)}{\log(n-1)\log(n)}$$

Apparently I can solve this by using the comparison test, but I don't know how this would be implemented in this exercise. Also, if it is possible, how can I find the result of the series?

Comment: Write it as $\frac{1}{\log(n)} - \frac{1}{\log(n-1)}$. Telescoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\log(n-1)-\log(n)}{\log(n-1) \log(n)}
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\log(n-1)}{\log(n-1) \log(n)}-\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n-1) \log(n)}\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{\log(n)}-\frac{1}{\log(n-1)}\right) \\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=3}^N\left( \frac{1}{\log(n)}-\frac{1}{\log(n-1)}\right) \\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\log N}-\frac{1}{\log 2}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{\log 2}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, how did you get $\frac{1}{log2}$ from the third to the fourth passage?

Comment: It's a telescoping series. In the partial sum note the following:
$$\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{\log (n)}-\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{\log(n-1)}=\sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{\log (n)}-\sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\log(n)}=\left(\sum_{n=3}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\log (n)}+\frac{1}{\log N}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{\log 2}+\sum_{n=3}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\log (n)}\right)=\frac{1}{\log N}-\frac{1}{\log 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n)}-\frac{1}{\log(n-1)}$$